# JPA Native query on Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jpa

I'm trying to do a native query on an Oracle database involve dates but I'm just not getting something.

I have a table with a number of rows in it and I know that the record with the oid=1234 has the latest updatetimeutc field, where updatetimeutc is a Date field. So I do the following:

```
Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select updatetimeutc from TABLE where oid=1234");
List<Object[]> resultList = query1.getResultList();
Object[] os = resultList.get(0);
Date date = os[0];

Query query2 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select oid, updatetimeutc from TABLE where updatetimeutc > :d");
query.setParameter("d", date);
resultList = query.getResultList();
```

At this point, I'm expecting the resultList.size() == 0, but that's not what's happening.  I'm getting the same row returned to me as in query1.

Can someone explain why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `Date` a `java.util.Date` or a `java.sql.Date`?  My guess is that it is a `java.sql.Date` which will ignore the time component of the Oracle `date`.  That causes the second query to see the parameter passed in as being midnight on the day in question which then returns the same row you queried for originally if the time component in Oracle is after midnight.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.  I get back a java.sql.Date from the first query.  If I construct a java.utl.Date with the .getTime() from the sql.Date, I get the same results.

Comment: If you get back a `java.sql.Date` and you print it out, you'll see that there is no time component.  If you print out the `date` value that is stored in Oracle, I'll wager that it does have a time component.  If you're dropping the time, that explains the behavior you're seeing.  I suspect that you want to do a `ResultSet.getTimestamp` to retrieve the value from Oracle.

Comment: Because I'm using a native query, I'm not getting back a ResultSet.  I'm getting back a List of Arrays of Objects.  What other way is there to get a Date field out of a native query fired at an Oracle DB??

Comment: I'm not, unfrotunately, a JPA expert.  I would expect, though, that you'd want to get a `java.sql.Timestamp` from your `resultList` rather than getting a `java.sql.Date`.  I was couching it in raw JDBC terms just because that's what I'm more familiar with.

Comment: Seems the solution was simpler than I thought: upgrade to a newer JDBC driver!  I was using an older driver and when upgraded to a new one, I started getting a java.sql.Timestamp in my Object array instead of java.sql.Date and things started working as expeced.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure you are using a version of Oracle's JDBC drivers that produce a java.sql.Timestamp for native queries that return DATE field.